# Consecutive values in a list (python)

Tags: python

I am trying to find if the following list contains more than 4 consecutive values.

hours=[9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

I have tried this code and returns that the list above has more than 4 consecutive values but it does not work for other numbers.

```
hours=[9,28,11,23,13,9,15]
y = sorted(hours)
consecutive_hours = 0

while consecutive_hours <=4:
    for hours in hours:
        if len(y) == 7 and y[6]-y[0] == 6: 
            consecutive_hours += 1
        else:
            break

if consecutive_hours > 4:
    print("The list", hours, "contains more than 4 consecutive hours.")
else:
    print("The list",hours, "does not contain more than 4 consecutive hours.")
```

Comment: Your question is not so clear, what exactly do you want to achieve, how does the output look like?

Comment: There is no way for your while-loop to end unless `consective_hours` reaches 4. Your break statement only breaks out of the for-loop.

Comment: @Ade_1 I need a code in order to check if a list has more than 4 consecutive values. In this case I have a list with different hours and I am trying to find a code for checking if the list contains more than 4 consecutive hours. 

hours= [9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
hours = [9, 28, 11, 23, 13, 9, 15]
y = sorted(hours)

# Starts with 1 consecutive hour, we will subtract later
consecutive_hours = 1

# Check for the number of consecutive hours
for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i] == y[i - 1] + 1:
        consecutive_hours += 1

if consecutive_hours == 1: consecutive_hours = 0

# Print results
if consecutive_hours > 4:
    print("The list ", hours, " contains more than 4 consecutive hours.")
else:
    print("The list ", hours, " does not contain more than 4 consecutive hours.")
```

Comment: Phan Nhật Huy, len(y) returns an integer. you can't loop over an integer. – Ade_1 7 mins ago   Delete

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
hours=[9,28,11,23,13,9,15]
y = sorted(hours)
consecutive_hours = 1

for i in range(0, len(y)):
        j = i + 1
        if j >= len(y):
            break
        if y[j] == y[i] + 1:
            consecutive_hours += 1
        elif consecutive_hours > 4:
            break
        else:
            consecutive_hours = 1

if consecutive_hours > 4:
    print("The list", hours, "contains more than 4 consecutive hours.")
else:
    print("The list",hours, "does not contain more than 4 consecutive hours.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will allow you to check if the next number in the list is the consecutive number to the current one the `for` loop is at, and if it is, it will add one to the `consecutive_hours` variable. If the `for` loop reaches a number that is not a consecutive number to the previous one, it will set `consecutive_hours` to `0`. If the `consecutive_hours` variable becomes greater than `4` before the `for` loop has iterated over the whole list, the `for` loop will break, and if the value is less than or equal to `4` when the loop reaches the end of the list, the loop will end. The following `if` statement after the `for` loop will check the `consecutive_hours` value, and print the appropriate statement.

```
hours=[9,28,11,23,13,14,15,16,17,9,15,1,2,3,4]
y = sorted(hours)
consecutive_hours = 0

for num in hours:
    if hours.index(num) == len(hours)-1:
        break
    elif hours[hours.index(num)+1] == num + 1:
        consecutive_hours += 1
        if consecutive_hours > 4:
            break
    else:
        consecutive_hours = 0

if consecutive_hours == 4:
    print("The list", hours, "contains more than 4 consecutive hours.")
else:
    print("The list",hours, "does not contain more than 4 consecutive hours.")
```

Comment: `hours.index(num)` ? what if list contains duplicates ?

Comment: @Andre Liberty I don't get what the problem is with this. The code works for detecting if 4 numbers are consecutive, which is what OP asked for. My way may not be as efficient as yours by doing this index thing, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting, you could use the Counter class (from collections) to count how many matches you get when combining all values with their offsets by 0,1,2 and 3:

```
from collections import Counter
def maxConsec(hours,span=4):
    counts = Counter(h-i for h in {*hours} for i in range(span))
    return span in counts.values()
```

output:

```
maxConsec([9,10,11,12,13,14,15]) # True
maxConsec([9,28,11,23,13,9,15])  # False
```